# Progressive packings in a convex shape

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polygons, packing-problem, tiling

Take a shape, and scale it by 1 to $n$.  For a tiny set of tightly related shapes, such as isosceles right triangles with shortest sides 1 and sqrt(2), scale the set of shapes by 1 to $n$.

What is the the smallest convex shape this progression of $n$ (or $2 n$) shapes can fit into?  For [tightly packed squares](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TightlyPackedSquares/) in rectangles, solutions up to $n=32$ are known ([OEIS A081287](https://oeis.org/A081287)).  No solutions above 32 are known. There are likely tighter solutions if all convex shapes are considered, but these rectangles provide a good starting point.  If the outer shape is a square [A081287](https://oeis.org/A081287) has some solutions, which were recently corrected for [37 squares](http://www.geocities.co.jp/Berkeley-Labo/6317/seq37.gif).

If you have 1 shape of size 1, 2 shapes of size 2, up to $n$ shapes of size $n$, you have the [partridge problem](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0802.html). In this variant, the 30-60-90 triangle has a perfect packing at $n=4$.

For the isosceles triangle set up to $n=11$, I'm fairly sure this is the smallest possible convex shape. What are the best solutions for smaller/larger $n$? (Can you find the perfect packing for $n=3$?)

[image: triangle sets 1 to 11]

For dominoes, there is a perfect packing at $n=2$.  What is the behavior of tight progressive domino packings as $n$ increases?

Math Magic has other [packing sequences](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0704.html). From the [no touch tiling](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0705.html) page, some other shapes are suggested that might be good at progressive packing, such as the tritan. The below is a tight but flawed solution, the two smallest tritans are omitted, and only one of them has a place to fit. The triamond and tridrafter might also be good shapes.

[image: tritan packing]

What are other good shapes to consider? For those shapes, what does the sequence of solutions look like?  What shapes have perfect convex packings when $n>4$? I suspect that the tritan and isosceles triangle both lend themselves to perfect solutions.